# PHP Session Cache limiter header error

Tags: php

i am beginner in php i search for hours and try everthing that i can but still getting this error. 
    Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/apsterne/public_html/mag/main.php:1) in /home/apsterne/public_html/mag/includes/functions.php on line 3

**this is my login page where i'm logging in and going for main page**

```
include_once('includes/functions.php');
include_once('includes/connection.php');
if(loggedin())
{
    header("location:main.php");
     exit();
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$error=array();
if($_POST['username']=="") $error[]='Please Enter Username'; 
if($_POST['password']=="") $error[]='Please Enter Password';
if(isset($_GET['e'])) $error[]='You Are Trying to access secure page without login';
if(isset($_POST['rememberme'])) $remember=$_POST['rememberme'];
function cleanStr($str) {
        $cStr = trim($str);
        $cStr = htmlspecialchars($cStr);
        $cStr = addslashes($cStr);
        return $cStr;
    }
        $userName = cleanStr($_POST['username']);
        $pwd = cleanStr($_POST['password']);


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(empty($error)){
                if($userName==$row['username'] && $pwd==$row['password'] ){ 
                    if($rememberme=="on")        
                          setcookie("username",$userName,time()+7200);
                   else if($rememberme==""){
                                    $_SESSION['username']=$userName;
                                    header("location:main.php");
                                    exit();
                                    }
                            }
                            else
                            $error[]='You Enter Wrong username and password';

            }
}
```

**THis is main page**

```
<?php
include_once('includes/functions.php');
include_once('includes/connection.php');
if(!loggedin())
{
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

**And This is Function File**

```
<?php
session_start();
function loggedin()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset ($_COOKIE['username']))
        {
         $loggedin=TRUE;
         return TRUE ;
        }
}
?>
```

There is no whitespace and i dont know what is this..

Comment: i simply copy all the contents to new file and then it works for me Thanks to all stackoverflow members... it was BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a blank line in one or more of your files or you saved some of them with UTF-8 encoding + bite order mark bytes. Try to save them with **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Comment: how can i save file without BOM

Comment: On Windows platform try notepad++ on any other try simething similar editor but for example Netbans saves the files without BOM.

Comment: Thanks i open a new file in notepadd++ and copy all the code to that and save that.. and it works for me... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you send any content (being non headers) before calling `session_start`.
Is there maybe trailing or leading whitespace? Did you encode your files at **utf-8 with BOM**?

For this reason it's generally recommended to omit the final `?>` php closing tag.

Comment: Ye  i encoded this file in utf-8 what do u mean by omitting the final ?> tag

Answer (score 1):

Double-check main.php. The engine is claiming that the very first line has output, possibly before the `<?php` tag. (Accidental BOM (byte-order mark for old UTF-8 files) character?)